# Aerospike: how do I get record key?

Tags: java, aerospike, nosql

Aerospike client has [scanAll](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/usage/scan/scan.html) method for reading all rows from it's store.
I use it in the folowing code:

```
ScanPolicy policy = new ScanPolicy();
policy.concurrentNodes = true;
policy.priority = Priority.DEFAULT;
policy.includeBinData = true;
policy.scanPercent = 100;

client.scanAll(policy, "namespaceName", "setName", new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void scanCallback(Key key, Record record) throws AerospikeException {
        STORE.put(key.userKey.toLong(), record.getValue("binName").toString());
    }
});
```

But it is finished with `NullPointerException`, because userKey is null. All other fields are valid as expected. User key is the Long value, that was used for saving data:

```
client.put(writePolicy, new Key("namespaceName", "setName", userKey), new Bin("binName", value));
```

All is fine, if I do single request like this:

```
client.get(readPolicy, new Key("namespaceName", "setName", userKey));
```

What may be wrong? Why userKey is null?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Aerospike uses key and set name to generate unique digest, So it stores only digest.

While inserting one record if you set `writePolicy.sendKey = true` then key will be stored as metadata of record. 
If one record is inserted with `writePolicy.sendKey = true` then only you will get key in scanCallback().

By default writePolicy.sendKey is false, so by default `scanCallback()` gets **null** as key. Thats why your `key.userKey.toLong()` gives **NullPointerException**.

Answer (score 3):

I too have faced this problem even at the time of writing we were setting the WritePolicy.sendkeys=true.

After 2-3 days debugging found that there were some issue with aerospike client version. Initially i were using 3.0.25 but after upgrading it to 3.0.35 it started working fine.