# How can i get aerospike pk value from secondary index through java client?

Tags: aerospike

I am inserting  LargeMap(LDT) through java client into aerospike .

the problem here is I can't retrieve LDT from secondary index(Correct me if there is an option through java client) so I am planning to get 'PK'from secondary index which will solve my use case.

Though i can create a bin which holds "PK" values I don't want to create that for some reasons. So please Suggest me the way to do it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use following parameter to store key in record.

```
writePolicy.sendKey = true;
```

Query using secondary index and use following to get key of record.

```
Key key = record.getKey();
```

If you already inserted records without setting 'sendkey' parameter then you can't retrieve your PK.

Answer (score 3):

You might find a similar response here at stackoverflow :

[Aerospike: how do I get record key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229399/aerospike-how-do-i-get-record-key/27233099#27233099)

Also refer this aerospike documentation : https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/usage/best_practices.html