# userKey returned in scanAll for Aerospike is null

Tags: aerospike

I am trying to scan an entire set in Aerospike, but in the callback function I am getting key.userKey as null.

I have tried making both `writePolicy.sendKey = true` and `scanPolicy.sendKey = true` but all in vain

I have the most recent AS java client version. (3.1.5)

Sample from put function:

```
            WritePolicy writePolicy = new WritePolicy();
            writePolicy.expiration = ABC;
            writePolicy.timeout = XYZ;
            writePolicy.sendKey = true;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229399/aerospike-how-do-i-get-record-key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may not have set `sendKey = true` on your scan policy.

[Here](https://github.com/helipilot50/store-primary-key) is an example that works.